# Как отцентрировать список внутри div'a?

Tags: html, css

Требуется сделать текст внутри дива по центру. Пытался через margin 0 auto, align-center, не получается. Может, дело в position?
Код ниже, на скринах показано как надо и как получается

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1180px;
    height: 80px;
    left: 370px;
    top: 20px;
    background: #E73D66;
    border-radius: 90px;

}

.pages {

    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="pages">О приюте</ul>
        <ul class="pages">Питомцы</ul>
        <ul class="pages">Полезные советы</ul>
        <ul class="pages">Контакты</ul>
    </div>
</body>

<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

[image: Как надо]

[image: Как получается]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, семантически правильно так:

```
  <ul class="header">
    <li class="pages">О приюте</li>
    <li class="pages">Питомцы</li>
    <li class="pages">Полезные советы</li>
    <li class="pages">Контакты</li>
  </ul>
```

Уже это, если хотите, можете положить в div. И помните, что любой список и не нумерованный тоже имеет отступы слева перед элементами списка. Уберите эти отступы и равняйте по центру любым доступным вам способом